# MYSQL Not unique table/alias on left join

Tags: mysql

I know this has been asked before but I cannot apply it to my scenario.

I am trying this query:

```
var sqlString1 = "SELECT 10561_12865_tblNotifications.forUserID, 10561_12865_tblNotifications.notificationType, 10561_12865_tblNotifications.message, 10561_12865_tblCircles.smallPic \
FROM 10561_12865_tblNotifications \
LEFT JOIN 10561_12865_tblNotifications ON 10561_12865_tblCircles.tblCircleID = 10561_12865_tblNotifications.identifier \
WHERE forUserID  = '" + "6" + "' \
LIMIT " + "0" + "," + 4
```

The context:

I have one table that stores notifications that a user recevies when he or she is invited to a circle (like a group).
But I dont just wanna show the notification, I also want to show the picture of the circle in the frontend. So I thought I join both tables together where the idenfier is equal to tblCircleID and then return the picture from that row together with all the data from the notifications table.

So basically return all data from one table and also return the picture from another table where tblCircleID = identifier and forUserID = 6.

But my above query fails.
Now I dont understand why I would need aliasing in the first place when both tables are unique?

Thanks for your help

Comment: where is the second table you talk about? I can see only one: 10561_12865_tblNotifications

Comment: it should be this: 10561_12865_tblCircles

Comment: @basha04I dont mean to join it twice. I have two tables and they need to be joined once. Can you show me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is produced because you are joining the same table without using an alias.

```
FROM 10561_12865_tblNotifications 
LEFT JOIN 10561_12865_tblNotifications ON 10561_12865_tblCircles.tblCircleID = 10561_12865_tblNotifications.identifier
```

This should be :

```
FROM 10561_12865_tblNotifications 
LEFT JOIN 10561_12865_tblCircles ON 10561_12865_tblCircles.tblCircleID = 10561_12865_tblNotifications.identifier
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding table to the where clause like:

`WHERE 10561_12865_tblNotifications.forUserID`

P.s post more code or error so we can help.